# Attach a file to a donation

Tags: activities, attachments

I'd like to be able to attach receipts, notes, and other documentation to a contribution. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Sam - welcome to civi SE. Can you flesh out a bit more about what you mean to 'attach receipts' since civi generates its own.

Comment: But may be redundant comment since i hadn't seen Andy's excellent answer below.

Answer (score 4):

In a word, yes.  You'll have to implement this as custom field sets, which is easy.  That's menu option Administer/Customize Data and Screens/Custom fields.  You can have a custom type of 'file' as a custom field, which then allows you to attach a file.  You can have as many of these fields as you require, and you can set the custom field set as applying to contributions only.